# Executing unix scripts using sshnet

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, ssh.net

I am trying to execute perl scripts on my UNIX machine, through SSH.
I have managed to connect to the machine and execute "ls" and "man chmod", but when I am trying "perl /test/temp.pl" or "perl a", I don't get anything back.

The code I am using is the following

```
PasswordConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new PasswordConnectionInfo(host, user,pass);
using (var client = new SshClient(connectionInfo))
{
    client.Connect();
    var cmd = client.CreateCommand(script);
    string result = cmd.Execute(script);
    var reader = new StreamReader(cmd.OutputStream);
    var output = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.Out.WriteLine(result + "_output:" + output);
}
```

Anybody having the same or similar issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
client.Connect();
SshCommand cmd = client.RunCommand(message);
var output =cmd.Result;
```

Comment: I have quit this approach and used another one, so I can't even test it any more. I am accepting your answer because I trust that you have tested something similar at least :)